# Problem with PageParserPaths when web.config on different port

Tags: 2007, web-config

I have ported a SP site from a dev server to a live server, as may be seen in other questions, and have another problem.

I have 1 page which uses some server side code to run. On dev it works, on live I get the error:

> Code blocks are not allowed in this file.

Now from previous experience with this I know that it has to do with the `PageParserPaths` which is the same on the dev and live server. I have used the line:

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/TestSite/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true"/>
```

Now the problem, I believe, is down to the fact that the web.config and the Sharepoint TestSite are on different ports. I.e. The Central Admin is located at `http://server:29110/default.aspx` and the TestSite is located at `http://server/TestSite/default.aspx`. So the web.config file is located in `VirtualDirectories/21190`

I may be getting completely confused about the different web.config files and this whole situation but I just need advice on where to look from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change your web.config file from:

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="/TestSite/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true"/>
```

to this:

```
<PageParserPath VirtualPath="~/TestSite/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true"/>
```

hope this help u..:)

Comment: What web.config file should I be changing?! If I change the one in the 21190 directory, nothing changes, if I add it to the one in the 80 directory I get the message, "An unexpected error has occurred."

Comment: Ok, adding them to the web.config in the 80 directory was the solution. The unexpected error was that I didn't have the correct ODBC driver installed. Now I've another problem but that's for another question!